# Finding where something is installed on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, paths

I am trying to find where someone has installed a software package, and I can not.  Is there a good way of finding that other than running a grep on the entire file system?

I am running Ubuntu and looking for an installation of a triple-store database called Virtuoso.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the other answers given handle package installations.  Without root level access there are few places a user can install software:

- ~ (Their home directory)
- /tmp (The temporary directory, package will likely disappear on next reboot.)
- /var/tmp (Alternate temp directory.  More likely to survive a reboot.)
- /var/lock (Publicly writeable.)
- Any other directories which they can write (none on a standard configuration).

Normal places to install packages not using the package manager include:

- /usr/local
- /var/local (variable components)
- /opt

Commands to find writable directories (for user somebody in group users).

```
sudo find / -type d -perm -02
sudo find / -type d -perm -020 -group users
sudo find / -type d -perm -0200 -user somebody
```

The user may belong to multiple groups.  Each group will need to be checked.

Comment: Combine this with my answer about using `locate`.

Answer (score 4):

```
whereis Virtuoso
```

Or, if the binary is called something else:

```
whereis name-of-binary
```

Or, if the software isnt located in the usual places (/bin, /sbin, /usr/bin etc)

```
which name-of-binary
```

Answer (score 3):

Was it installed using `apt` or `dpkg`? If so you can use `dpkg -l |grep <name>` to find the packages and `dpkg -L <package name>` to find where it installed the files.

If it was not installed using the package management system, look at `/opt` and `/usr/local` first, and if it fails, use `find / -iname <what you are searching>` to search the whole filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

If you installed with apt or dkpg

```
dpkg -L virtuoso
```

will show you the location of all the files installed.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget the `locate(1)` command. If this is set up, `updatedb` runs nightly on your machine and creates an index of all files.  Then for example

```
$ locate myprogram
```

will give you every file which contains `myprogram` (in the filename *or* path) on the system.

If you know the exact name of the binary, you can use a regexp match to find it, for example:

```
$ locate --regexp="myprogram$"
```

will list all files which end in `myprogram` on your system.

Two caveats:

1. Many systems ship with updatedb turned off by default.
2. The index is generally rebuilt once a day, so it will always be somewhat out-of-date.

`locate` can be a good way to get a sense of where on the system a particular file might be, before you drill down to looking for the package.